# Share Twitter state by PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, twitter, cordova

I want to share my result to Twitter by one click in the iPhone.

Comment: As it stands this is not a real question. Try to find available material online. Try to implement what you're trying to achieve. And if you have a practically answerable question, come back and ask it. "Give me the code/tutorial"-type questions are not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at this plugin and see if it fits the bill:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Twitter